# How to find first value in a list having no duplicates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
l1 = ['A','B','C','D','A','B']
l2 = []
```

'C' is the first value in list l1, i want to create a function so that it returns C in l2.

Answer (score 10):

In 3.6 and higher, this is *very* easy. Now that `dict`s preserve insertion order, `collections.Counter` can be used to efficiently count *all* elements in a single pass, then you can just scan the resulting `Counter` in order to find the first element with a count of 1:

```
from collections import Counter

l1 = ['A','B','C','D','A','B']
l2 = [next(k for k, v in Counter(l1).items() if v == 1)]
```

Work is strictly `O(n)`, with only one pass of the input required (plus a partial pass of the unique values in the `Counter` itself), and the code is incredibly simple. In modern Python, `Counter` even has a C accelerator for counting inputs that pushes all the `Counter` construction work to the C layer, making it impossible to beat. If you want to account for the possibility that no such element exists, just wrap the `l2` initialization to make it:

```
try:
    l2 = [next(k for k, v in Counter(l1).items() if v == 1)]
except StopIteration:
    l2 = []
    # ... whatever else makes sense for your scenario ...
```

or avoid exception handling with `itertools.islice` (so `l2` is 0-1 items, and it still short-circuits once a hit is found):

```
from itertools import islice

l2 = list(islice((k for k, v in Counter(l1).items() if v == 1), 1))
```

Comment: @ShadowRanger Never mind, I think I got the point now  (and deleted previous comment). However the insertion order preservation can be rellied upon starting with 3.7 according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/5378816

Comment: @VPfB: Yeah, for 3.6, you can only *rely* on it for CPython (the reference interpreter) and PyPy (which first debuted the `dict` design that was naturally ordered). But as of 3.7 it's a language guarantee, not merely something that works as an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `list` to `string` and then compare `index` of each character from left and right using `find` and `rfind` functions of string. It stops counting as soon as the first match is found,

```
l1 = ['A','B','C','D','A','B']

def i_list(input):
    l1 = ''.join(input)
    for i in l1:
        if l1.find(i) == l1.rfind(i):
            return(i)


print(i_list(l1))

# output
C
```

Answer (score 1):

An implementation using a defaultdict:

```
# Initialize
from collections import defaultdict
counts = defaultdict(int)

# Count all occurrences
for item in l1: 
    counts[item] += 1

# Find the first non-duplicated item
for item in l1:
    if counts[item] == 1: 
        l2 = [item]
        break
else:
    l2 = []
```

Comment: One liners are more appreciated.

Comment: @TheInfectedDrake Says who?

Comment: Heh. This answer isn't so bad, and back in the Python 2 days, it would be the fastest (`Counter` wasn't C accelerated back then, `defaultdict` is, and neither of them was insertion ordered, so looping over the input a second time was the easiest way to find the first unique item). It's just that `Counter` got faster (specifically for one-liner usage counting a few larger iterables), and `dict`s got insertion ordered (allowing you to avoid reiterating the input iterable), so my solution ends up winning on both performance and simplicity. I'll kick in an upvote though. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger I know your solution is faster - I timed all of them :)

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up to [ShadowRanger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53201925/1822698), if you're using a lower version of Python, it's not that more complicated to filter the *original list* so that you don't have to rely on the ordering of the counter items:

```
from collections import Counter

l1 = ['A','B','C','D','A','B']
c = Counter(l1)
l2 = [x for x in l1 if c[x] == 1][:1]

print(l2)  # ['C']
```

This is also *O(n)*.

Comment: You don't need `filter`, and you can still short-circuit. `l2 = [next(x for x in l1 if c[x] == 1)]` (with similar `StopIteration` handling if desired). Any use of `filter` that needs a `lambda` should really just be a listcomp or genexpr, so if you don't mind complete iteration a second time, this code could still be improved to `[x for x in l1 if c[x] == 1][:1]`.

Comment: *Any use of filter that needs a lambda should really just be a listcomp or genexpr* That is good to know. Thank you :) I'll skip short circuiting as your comment and answer explain it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it also with "numpy".

```
def find_first_non_duplicate(l1):
    indexes_counts = np.asarray(np.unique(l1, return_counts=True, return_index=True)[1:]).T
    (not_duplicates,) = np.where(indexes_counts[:, 1] == 1)
    if not_duplicates.size > 0:
        return [l1[np.min(indexes_counts[not_duplicates, 0])]]
    else:
        return []

print(find_first_non_duplicate(l1))

# output
['C']
```

Answer (score 0):

### **A faster way to get the first unique element in a list:**

1. Check each element one by one and store it in a `dict`.
2. Loop through the `dict` and check the first element whose count is

   ```
   def countElement(a):
       """
       returns a dict of element and its count
       """
       g = {}
       for i in a:
           if i in g: 
               g[i] +=1
           else: 
               g[i] =1
       return g


   #List to be processed - input_list
   input_list = [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,234,23,3,12,3,123,12,31,23,13,2,4,23,42,42,34,234,23,42,34,23,423,42,34,23,423,4,234,23,42,34,23,4,23,423,4,23,4] #Input from user


   try:
       if input_list: #if list is not empty
           print ([i for i,v in countElement(input_list).items() if v == 1][0]) #get the first element whose count is 1
       else: #if list is empty
           print ("empty list in Input")
   except: #if list is empty - IndexError
       print (f"Only duplicate values in list - {input_list}")
   ```

Comment: This is a slower (thanks to repeated tests for membership and Python level loops, as well as not short-circuiting when it finds the first element with a count of 1), *much* more verbose way of doing what [`collections.Counter` can do for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53201925/364696) (and [`defaultdict(int)` could do a lot of it too for that matter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53201914/364696)), with the same limitations (only works on 3.6+ as it relies on `dict`s being insertion ordered). Generally, if the goal is counting, you want to use `collections.Counter`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Thanks for your valuable suggestions. Short-circuiting is something that I learned in this thread.